# Database access library to use with spray

Tags: scala, spray

I am considering rewriting a large project using `Spray`. I am unsure what is currently the best choice for accessing an RDBMS. I need to support `Oracle` and `PosgreSQL` and, as I am restricted to a free solution, `Slick` is rather not an option here.

I often use `MyBatis` in my `Java` projects, so I consider `MyBatis-Scala` as a possible solution, but this is just a wrapper for a `Java` library.

Which native `Scala` library fits best into `Spray`?

Answer (score 1):

In my oppinion it is not the matter of "fitting" into Spray, but the matter of good strategic choice.

Please consider [options](https://github.com/lauris/awesome-scala) of scala database frameworks. My personal preference is [squeryl](https://github.com/squeryl/squeryl) and [sorm](https://github.com/sorm/sorm). Both of them provide pretty much nice DSL and are written in scala.

Also you can have a look at one more review of [available scala frameworks](http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2014/02/04/a-quick-tour-of-relational-database-access-with-scala/) (a bit outdated but well structured to give a basic idea).

Hope it helps.